# Display three months in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is there any way to display 3 consecutive months in the Fuill Calendar. I have to work with the month view and I searched a lot but I haven't found any solution.
this what I want to do. 
**More details** : I'm using Javascript
I tryed this but it didn't do what I want exactly.

```
var calendar = $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'title'
            }
        });
        var calendar = $('#calendar2').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'title'
            }
        });
        var calendar = $('#calendar3').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'title'
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. Please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), specifically [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: provide more details on the problem. are you trying in java script or any other UI ..?  if java script , did you try JQuery datepicker ..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Just Found the solution for this

```
fcViews.month = {
'class': MonthView,
duration: { months: 3 },
defaults: {
    fixedWeekCount: false
}};
```

Comment: can you tell me this where did you write this code?

Comment: This is in the fullcalendar.js
You have to search the function "fcViews.month" and change it as I did